# How to verify huge number in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a task to filter out a number which is bigger than `9e+65` (65 zeros).
As input I have a number and as output I need to return a boolean value. The function can accept regular formatted numbers (`42342`) and any scientific notation (`1e5`).

My approach is:

```
const 65zerosCheck = (num: number):boolean =>
  num.toString().includes("e+")
    : Number(value.toString().split('e+')[1]) > 65
      : false
```

It looks dirty and the reviewer didn't accept it.

Comment: The name of the function is not correct. It can not begin with a number. May be that's the reason the reviewer rejected it? Anyway, what's the error you get if you try it this way? `const checkHugeNumbers = (num) => num > 9e+65;`

Comment: will it cover case 99999 ... 999? Or 9e+65 is equal 9000 .... 000 ?

Comment: I tested with something like 900000000...0000 (66 zeroes) and it worked.

Comment: You should ask the reviewer what you need to change since they clearly have an opinion about that.

Answer (score 2):

To quote MDN:

> In JavaScript, numbers are implemented in double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 (i.e., a number between ±2^−1022 and ±2^+1023, or about ±10^−308 to ±10^+308, with a numeric precision of 53 bits). Integer values up to ±2^53 − 1 can be represented exactly.

You do not have to worry about such huge numbers. I have added a link to MDN quote above at the end of this snippet where it is discussed in details about how Javascript handles Numbers.

```js
const HUGE_NUMBER_THRESHOLD = 9e+65;

const checkHugeNumbers = (num) => num > HUGE_NUMBER_THRESHOLD;

let myTestNum = 9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

console.log(checkHugeNumbers(myTestNum));

// OUTPUT:
// true
```

For further study, here is the [reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#numbers).

Comment: This isn't _quite_ accurate, but your point is well taken. For what it is worth, the largest int that can be expressed by a `number` in JS is `2^53 - 1`, which is stored in [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). Because the question specifically says it accepts `number` types, you are correct that no value could exceed this threshold. However, FWIW, larger ints _can_ be expressed in the [`BigInt` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything logically wrong with your approach, but if your reviewer is asking for a cleaner approach, this is my suggestion.

It does the same thing, but is more readable and its easy to add on to, in the future. Splitting up the logic and results into descriptive variables makes it easier to read, and catch any errors or oversights that may be encountered.

Also you can save a step by directly getting the index, without using split and creating three types (array, string, and number), that can make it confusing to follow. This approach keeps everything between strings and numbers

```css
const checkOver65Zeros = (num: number) =>{
  const numString = num.toString()
  const idxOfZeros = numString.indexOf("e+")
  if(idxOfZeros!== -1) 
    return Number(numString.substring(idxOfZeros + 2)) > 65
  return false
}

console.log(checkOver65Zeros(900000000000000000000000000000000000000))
```